# PHP possible to open Private browser with selenium?

Tags: php, firefox, selenium

I'm using the selenium phpunit from sebastian bergmann. ( facebook Webdriver)
How I setup for a normal Firefox browser:

```
public function setUp()
    {
        // Browser Choice
        $capabilities = array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
        // Some more code to setup
    }
```

**Question:**

Now I want to open a Firefox browser but in private mode.
How would I do that and would it be the same way to open chrome/IE private browsering?

Comment: That doesn't look like phpunit-selenium but more like Facebook's php-webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

I have no selenium install at my disposal at the moment. So this is untested.

```
$profile = new FirefoxProfile();

$profile->setPreference(
  'browser.privatebrowsing.autostart',
  true
);

$capabilities = array(
    \FirefoxDriver::PROFILE, $profile
);
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work I'm getting the error: UnknownServerException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map
Googling now what could be this issue